# Reactflow, drag and drop to a parent node

Tags: react-flow

I can't drop a node as a child of another node when drop from a external sidebar.

I try two attempts. I was inspired in doc. In onDrop function I put this code trying that one of them works

[Collision Detection from doc](https://reactflow.dev/examples/interaction/collision-detection)

```
const centerX = newNode.position.x + newNode.width / 2;
const centerY = newNode.position.y + newNode.height / 2;

// find a node where the center point is inside
const targetNode = nodes.find(
    (n) =>
        centerX > n.position.x &&
        centerX < n.position.x + n.width! &&
        centerY > n.position.y &&
        centerY < n.position.y + n.height! &&
        n.id !== newNode.id // this is needed, otherwise we would always find the dragged node
);
```

[Intersections from doc](https://reactflow.dev/examples/nodes/intersections)

```
const intersections = getIntersectingNodes(newNode).map((n) => n.id);

nodes.forEach((n) => {
    if ( intersections.includes(n.id) ) {
        console.log("INTERSECTA")
    } else {
        console.log("NO INTERSECTA")
    }
    return ({
        ...n,
        className: intersections.includes(n.id) ? 'highlight' : '',
    })
})
```

Here is a simple code sandbox

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactflow-7qklx7?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00063b6ik9krkkpr%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00023b6ic1bz8ozs%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00033b6isgldmj1q%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00053b6iwfrvn61f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltvnnrsr00023b6ic1bz8ozs%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00023b6ic1bz8ozs%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522cltvnnrsr00053b6iwfrvn61f%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00053b6iwfrvn61f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltvnxlbi00cw3b6i93dqtcvi%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnxlbi00cw3b6i93dqtcvi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cltvnnrsr00033b6isgldmj1q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltvnnrsr00033b6isgldmj1q%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: I got a good way to solve my problem by going to the react-flow discord, I found a possible answer there in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dark-forest-rmtyrf?file=%2FApp.js%3A74%2C19-74%2C22)